# Django Loop conditional button classes in html

Tags: html, django

How can I achieve that buttons on default are green when the student is available, but when they are taken (added into the classList) then the button turns red.

```
{% for student in studentList %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.teacher }}</td>
    {% for class in classList %}
      {% if student.id == class.student_id and class.week == 14 %}
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Not Available</a></td>
      {% else %}
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Book Student</a></td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class ClassView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'class/index.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Classes.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ClassesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    classList = [x.student_id for x in Classes.objects.all() if x.week == 14]

    context['classList'] = classList
    context['studentList'] = Student.objects.all()
    return context
```

So imagine, all the students are available for now, but as soon they are booked (appears inside the classroom list) the button for those students should be red.

As it now, it query the database and looks for the correct details. But if the classroom list is bigger than 1, then the loop create buttons all over the place. Instead only place buttons due to the if condition.

[image]

Comment: When does a student become unavailable? When he's been booked into one class? Or how many classes?

Comment: Well there is classes expand in different weeks. So if i book today, the student will be unavailable until next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's creating a lot of buttons because you're doing two for loops.

You could extract a list of ids in your views and check if the student id is inside

```
# views.py
# in your request handler
...
classList = [x.student_id for x in classList if x.week == 14]
classIdDict = {}
for class in classList:
    classIdDict[class.student_id] = class
context = {
    ...your other context,
    'classList': classList,
    'classIdDict': classIdDict
}
return render(request, 'your-template.html', context)

# your-template.html
...
{% for student in studentList %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.teacher }}</td>
  {% if student.id in classList %}
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Not Available</a></td>
  {% else %}
    {% with student.id as student_id %}
    <td><a href="{% url 'nti:classes_detail' id=classIdDict.student_id.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Book Student</a></td>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: One thing, if i would like to send the user the class id in the html? How can i do that? Since i going to put it in the link.

Comment: I would like to do this on the book student button:
`href="{% url 'nti:classes_detail' classes.id %}"`

Comment: you can do something like `href="{% url 'nti:classes_detail' id=classes.id %}"` assuming your url is `url(r'.../<int:id>/', ..., name='classes_detail')`

Comment: how can i retrive the `classes.id`, since i need the primary key of that class which the student is booked on. Since now we are only sending the student id to the index.html

Comment: Updated the answer, we'll create a dictionary to store a mapping of student id to class object

Comment: No problem, happy to help!